# Need help with STL sort algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, sorting

I'm having some troubles with using the std::sort algorithm here. I was reading that you can just overload the less than operator to sort classes, but I have been getting all sorts of errors. I have also tried using a functor as you can see in the example I made below.

I was hoping somebody could see what I'm doing wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

class Thing {
public:
    Thing(int val) {
        this->_val = val;
    }

    bool operator<(Thing& rhs) {
        std::cout << "this works!";
        return this->val() < rhs.val();
    }

    int val() {
        return this->_val;
    }
protected:
    int _val;
};

struct Sort {
    bool operator()(Thing& start, Thing& end) {
        return start.val() < end.val();
    }
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    std::srand(std::time(NULL));

    std::vector<Thing> things;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Thing myThing(std::rand());
        things.push_back(myThing);
    }

    if(things[1] < things[2]) {
        //This works
    }

    //std::sort(things.begin(), things.end()); //This doesn't

    //std::sort(things.begin(), things.end(), Sort()); //Neither does this

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::cout << things.at(i).val() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to change

```
bool operator()(Thing& start, Thing& end) {
```

into

```
bool operator()(const Thing& start, const Thing& end) {
```

and

```
int val() {
```

into

```
int val() const {
```

IOW, your code needs to be const-correct and not claim it may modify things it in fact doesn't (nor needs to).

Answer (score 4):

Make your `val()` and `operator<()` `const` functions.

The same for `Sort::operator()` — take `const Thing&` instead of `Thing&`.

Comment: It's `operator<()` instead of `opeartor<()`. I couldn't edit it since the fix is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Try making operator< take its argument by const reference.  You'll need to change its implementation to directly access _val or (preferably) make val() const as well when you do this (because a const member function can't call a non-const one).